# DataTable dataset with JSON

Tags: php, json, datatable, html-table

I'm trying to use DataTable to show all fields of my JSON, but I'm not understand how to use it.

I just need how to populate dataset correctly to read data.

```
<script>
        <?php
            var jqxhr = $.ajax({url: api_ricerca_ingredienti, type: "GET",dataType: "json", data: {all: 1, ln : "it",completo:"-1",conteggio: 1}} )
              var max=json.items.length;
              for (i=0;i<max;i++){
                var el=json.items[i];
              }
              $(".risultato_ricerca").click(function() {
                carica_ingrediente($(this).attr('data-id'));
              });
            })
            <?php }?>

            var dataSet = [
              /*HOW?*/
            ];

            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#example').DataTable( {
                data: dataSet,
                columns: [
                  { title: "Nome" },
                  { title: "Stato" },
                  { title: "Home" },
                  { title: "Utente" },
                  { title: "Mi piace" },
                  { title: "Contributi" }
                ]
              } );
            } );
            </script>
            <table id="example" class="table table-responsive table-hover table-dynamic filter-head"></table>
```

Comment: You need a better understanding of the difference between PHP and Javascript.  The code that you have between your PHP tags is not PHP.

Comment: You are right. Thank you, i'm a newbie and i didn't understand that difference.

In any case, do you know how can i populate my dataset with the 6 fields from my json?

Thank you again.

Comment: Well it would be really helpful to know how your json is build or we can't know how to manipulate it into the correct structure

Comment: I've prepared an api that make an object array after some sql:
"Object {id: "1457449151.anacardo-cashew-9a6bbc", imm_home: Object, nome: "Anacardo", slug: "anacardo", utente: "redazione"…}completo: "Pubblico"countingredienti: "0"home: "Sì"id: "1457449151.anacardo-cashew-9a6bbc"imm_home: Objectlikes: "1"nome: "Anacardo"slug: "anacardo"utente: "redazione"

In the past, i made a manual table in this way:
var max=json.items.length;
        for (i=0;i<max;i++){
        var el=json.items[i];
        html+='<tr><td><span class="risultato_ricerca" data-id="'+el.id+'">etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, two comments about your code.
As @Patrick Q stated, your PHP tags are useless: you are writing Javascript, PHP is another things that has nothing to do with your code, so remove `<?php` and `<?php }?>`

Then, i can't understand this code:

```
for (i=0;i<max;i++){
   var el=json.items[i];
}
```

This for is completely useless. you cycle through every element in `json.items` without performing any operation. At the end you just store the last `json.items` in the `el` (without even using el in your code).

By the way, your main question:
As said in the [official documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html), your dataSet must contain an array for every row of your table in the format:

```
var dataSet = [
    ["john","italy","home","john",15,20],
    ["john","italy","home","john",15,20]
]
```

This example will create two identical rows with random data inside.

Assuming every item in your json has `name country home user likes contribs` fields you will need something like that:

```
var dataSet = []; 
for (i=0;i<json.items.length;i++){
     var el = [json.items[i].name,json.items[i].country, json.items[i].home, json.items[i].user, json.items[i].likes, json.items[i].contribs]
     dataSet[i] = el;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. I've truncated my prev code. Now the building of data array works like a charm. I've just a doubt about a console error:
"jquery.dataTables.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined"

I can't show my rows. According with your opinion, what's the problem?

Thank you!

```
<script>
< ?php
if (isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['id'])){
             ?>
             $( document ).ready(function() {
               carica_ingrediente('<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>');
            });
          <?php }else {?>
            $('#query').keypress(function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
                $('#cerca').click();
              }
            });
          $(document).ready(function() {
              var jqxhr = $.ajax({url: api_ricerca_ingredienti, type:   "GET",dataType: "json", data: {all: 1, ln : "it",completo:"-1",conteggio: 1}} )
              .done(function(json) {
                if (json.res==0){
                  alert( "Inserisci una parola per iniziare la ricerca " );
                  return;
                }
                var dataSet = [];
                for (i=0;i<json.items.length;i++){
                  var el = [json.items[i].nome,json.items[i].completo, json.items[i].home, json.items[i].utente, json.items[i].likes, json.items[i].countingredienti];
                  dataSet[i] = el;
                  console.log(el);
                }
                $(".risultato_ricerca").click(function() {
                  carica_ingrediente($(this).attr('data-id'));
                });

                $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('#example').DataTable( {
                    data: dataSet,
                    columns: [
                      { title: "Nome" },
                      { title: "Stato" },
                      { title: "Home" },
                      { title: "Utente" },
                      { title: "Mi piace" },
                      { title: "Contributi" }
                    ]
                  } );
                } );
              })
              .fail(function() {
                alert( "error" );
              });

            });

            <?php }?>
            </script>
```